# HUGO converts relative URLS to absolute

Tags: hugo

I have a configuration that looks like this:

```
[[menu.main]]
    name = "Team Profile"
    url = "/team/"
    weight = 24
    parent = "about"
```

But when I look at the code in developer console in Chrome it looks like this:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com//team/">Team Profile</a>
```

I want it to look like this:

```
<a href="/team/">Team Profile</a>
```

What should I look for as to why it is changing the URL?

I do not have any reference to `canonifyURLs` nor `relativeURLs` in my config files.

[EDIT]
I checked for absURL and found this:

```
layouts/partials/head.html:    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "css/style.css" | absURL }} ">  -->
layouts/partials/header.html:                            <img src="{{ .Site.Params.logo | safeHTML | absURL }}" alt="{{.Site.Title }}">
themes/tapp/layouts/partials/header.html:                            <img src="{{ .Site.Params.logo | safeHTML | absURL }}" alt="{{.Site.Title }}">
```

[EDIT]
I looked at `themes/XX/layouts/partials/header.html` and found this:

```
{{ range .Site.Menus.main }}
        {{ if .HasChildren }}
                <li class="menu-item-has-children">
                        <a href="{{ .URL | relLangURL }}"> {{ .Name }}</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                                {{ range .Children }}
                                        <li><a href="{{ .URL | relLangURL }}">{{ .Name }}</a></li>
                                {{ end }}
                        </ul>
                </li>
        {{ else }}
                <li><a href="{{ .URL | relLangURL }}"> {{ .Name }}</a> </li>
        {{ end }}
{{end}}
```

[EDIT]  Per suggestion, I changed to this:

```
{{ range .Site.Menus.main }}
        {{ if .HasChildren }}
                <li class="menu-item-has-children">
                        <a href="{{ .url }}"> {{ .Name }}</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                                {{ range .Children }}
                                        <li><a href="{{ .url }}">{{ .Name }}</a></li>
                                {{ end }}
                        </ul>
                </li>
        {{ else }}
                <li><a href="{{ .url }}"> {{ .Name }}</a> </li>
        {{ end }}
{{end}}
{{ if .Site.Params.freeTrial.enable }}
        <li><a class="btn-free" href="{{ .url }}"> Free Trial of Apps </a> </li>
{{ end }}
```

and it works.

Comment: You will need to check the template you are using. There might be a call to `absURL` in the code that generates the menu.

Comment: Instead of searching for `absURL` in your project, look for the template that's generating the HTML of the menu.

Comment: @josephting AFAIK the template is in my source code so it should have found it when I did the grep -r.  Could you advise on how I can confirm that I am not dependent on an external template?  I want all my dependencies to be in the source or at least documented.

Comment: @MichaelPotter The thing is, it's not even confirmed if `absURL` is used here even though it's highly likely. You have to find the template file that's generating the menu HTML and find out. Though, you should be able to find it with `.Site.Menus.main`.

Comment: What happens when you just put `{{ .url }}`?